# Does using CopyObjectRequest for converting from AWS S3 Reduced Redundancy Storage Class to Standard convert all segments of a large S3 record

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm using `com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.CopyObjectRequest`
to convert Reduced Redundancy Storage Class to Standard Storage Class:

```
StorageClass targetStorageClass = StorageClass.Standard;

CopyObjectRequest copyObjectRequest= 
                new CopyObjectRequest(bucket, key, bucket, key)
                .withStorageClass(targetStorageClass);

s3Client.copyObject(copyObjectRequest);
```

Will this work for all segments of a large record (>5G)?

Comment: Have you tested this on a large object?  I would expect it to fail outright, on an object > 5GB.

Comment: I finally got a clean test and it fails:The specified copy source is larger than the maximum allowable size for a copy source: 5368709120. I now need to find out if it fails on all multipart files even if < 5G

Comment: It *should* be fine for anything smaller, since it will copy the object *en bloc* as a single object, rather than in parts. The new object ETag should also revert to using the standard algorithm.  Copying objects > 5GB requires the use of the multipart upload API's [**`PUT` Part + Copy**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/mpUploadUploadPartCopy.html) capability (however that's exposed in the SDK), which is used identically to **`PUT` Part**, except the payload is transferred internally, using specified byte ranges.

Comment: Michael - Thanks! That covers all of the issues I had.